# Почему объект не получает атрибуты и методы класса после __new__ в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`Index` объекты `diskcahe` имеют свойство `_cache` с объектом `Cache` внутри него. 'Cache' создается с аргументами, передаваемыми в `Index`. К сожалению, последний учитывает не все аргументы, среди которых  нужные мне. Таким образом у меня было два выхода: либо редактировать пакет, что снизит универсальность моего кода, либо использовать метод `fromcache` у `Index`, в который я могу отправить `Cache` с нужными свойствами. Я решил попробовать последнее.

При этом я хотел бы добавить некоторые атрибуты и методы к этому объекту из `Index.fromcache()` и сделать его тип `GeoCache`. Я сконструировал следующий класс для этой цели:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import *
from collections.abc import *

import re

import geocoder
from geocoder.arcgis import ArcgisResult
from geocoder.yandex import YandexResult
from diskcache import Index, Cache

class GeoCache(Index):
    CYRILLIC_LETTERS_PATTERN = re.compile(r"[А-Я]")
    
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return Index.fromcache(Cache(*args, **kwargs))
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.request_map = self.cache["request-address"]
        except KeyError:
            self.request_map = self.cache["request-address"] = {}
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(self.request_map[key])
        except KeyError:
            query = self.getGeocodeData(key).current_result
            GeoCache.request_map[key] = query.address
            self[query.address] = query
            return query
    
    @classmethod
    def getGeocodeData(cls, address: str) -> geocoder.api.ArcgisQuery | geocoder.api.YandexQuery:
        n = 10

        def call() -> geocoder.api.ArcgisQuery | geocoder.api.YandexQuery:
            try:
                if "Russia" in address:
                    return geocoder.yandex(location=address, key=YANDEX_APIKEY, lang="en_RU")
                if re.search(cls.CYRILLIC_LETTERS_PATTERN, address):
                    return geocoder.yandex(location=address, key=YANDEX_APIKEY, lang="ru_RU")
                return geocoder.arcgis(location=address)
            except:
                raise Exception(address)

        for _ in range(n):
            response = call()
            if response.ok:
                return response
        raise Exception(f"I got error {n} times in row with {address}")
    
    def close(self) -> NoReturn:
        self.cache["request-address"] = self.request_map
        super().cache.close()
```

Но он выдаёт только объект `Index`. Например, вызов `close` дает `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'close'`. Почему объект не принимает методы и атрибуты класса после `__new__`?

Comment: Почему простого наследования не достаточно?

Comment: @PavelDurmanov Ну там вон инициализация какая-то хитрая

Comment: @Pavel Durmanov Потому что Вы не сможете определять значения определённых аргументов, так как `Cache` будет вызван в родительском `__init__` без них.

Comment: так сделайте `GeoCache.from_cache(...)`, в своем ините вызовите `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`, и потом уже делайте что хотите

Answer (score 0):

[Оригинальный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71765724/17309108)

Объект вызывает метод `__init__` и получает все свойства класса только в том случае, если его класс при выходе из `__new__` совпадает с блоком класса, в котором `__new__` прописан. Таким образом, проблему можно решить через `instance.__class__ = cls`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class GeoCache(Index):
    ...
    
    @classmethod
    def fromcache(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super().fromcache(*args, **kwargs)
        if cls.__init__ is not super().__init__:
            instance.__init__()
```

Но, я бы не рекомендовал использовать `__init__`, библиотека этого явно не позволяет. По сути Ваш код начинает зависеть на внутреннюю реазилацию библиотеки, и есть большая вероятность, что все сломается даже при смене минорной версии библиотеки.

Поэтому лучше использовать свой, кастомный метод для дополнительной инициализации обьекта:

```py
class BaseGeoCache(Index):

    @classmethod
    def fromcache(cls, *args, post_init=None, **kwargs):
        cache = Cache(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = super().fromcache(cache)
        instance.post_init(**(post_init or {}))
        return instance

    def post_init(self, **kwargs):
        ...


class GeoCache(BaseGeoCache):
    def post_init(self, default_request_address):
        try:
            self.request_map = self.cache["request-address"]
        except KeyError:
            self.request_map = self.cache["request-address"] = default_request_address
```

Теперь Вы полностью контролируете инициализацию обьекта:

```py
obj = GeoCache.fromcache(..., post_init={"default_request_address": {}})
```

Comment: Таким образом мы запускаем родительский `__init__` который создаёт один кэш на диске, а потом должны ещё вызвать отдельно `fromcache`, который создаёт другой или переиспользует первый. Это некрасиво и неэффективно. Можно тогда было бы отнаследоваться от `Index`, не использовать `__new__`, и после инициализации запустить `geocache.cache.reset(*args, **kwargs)`. `geocache = GeoCache(*args, **kwargs)` выглядит лучше, если после этого ничего не надо вызывать.

Comment: @Vovin мы не вызываем родительский инит если он не переопределен в наследнике

Comment: То есть, Вы предлагаете создавать объект таким образом: `geocache = Geocache.fromcache(Cache(*args, **kwargs))`?

Comment: Да, таким образом

Comment: либо делать обьект кеша в контрукторе fromcache

Comment: а вообще, я бы не советовал трогать инит явно, нияего не мешает сделать отдельный метод для ваших нужд

Comment: Тогда вариант, конечно, но я уже сделал как описал в своём ответе и это выглядит лаконичнее, хотя это вопрос вкуса.

Comment: нет, это в корне не верно и не выглядит лаконичнее, переопределять класс обьекта слишком не надежно и не будет работать при множественном наследовании

Comment: Думаю, Вы правы. Можно ещё сделать инъекцию декоратором и тогда будет и нормальное наследование и `__class__` не придётся трогать.

Comment: @Vovin обновил ответ